# How to clear model using javascript in asp.net core razor pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor-pages

There is an error message set using

```
ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Your Email/Password is incorrect");
```

I want to reset the model using `ModelState.Clear()` when a user types something on a text box so that the error message goes away. How can I do this?

Comment: You title is to clear model using js but your question is how to use `Modelstate.Clear()`.Could you share more details about your requirement?

Comment: If you use Unobtrusive Validation, the error message should disappear as soon as the error is corrected by the user: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation#client-side-validation